.NET Dependency Injection - Validate on startup on a non IOptions object
I am trying to load a json file and a json schema file on app startup and validate the json using the loaded schema.
I only see for the AddOptions<> the possibility to run validations on startup.
Is it possible to do something simular but on the TryAddSingleton() method?
Or maybe with another method?
Currently I have the following to load and register the strongly typed models of my json file.
private static IServiceCollection AddConfig<TConfig>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    string jsonSchemaPath)
    where TConfig : class, IConfig
{
services.TryAddSingleton((sp) =>
{
    var configService = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfigService>();
    var config = configService.LoadAsync<TConfig>(
        jsonSchemaPath)
    .GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult();

    if (config is null)
    {
        throw new ConfigMissingException(nameof(TConfig));
    }

    bool valid = config.Validate();

    if (!valid)
    {
        throw new ConfigInvalidException(
            nameof(TConfig),
            config
                .GetValidationErrors()
                .ToList());
    }

    return config;
});

return services;
}

UPDATE
services
.AddOptions<TConfig>()
.Configure<IConfigService>((config, configService) =>
{
    var c = configService.LoadAsync<TConfig>(
    jsonSchemaPath)
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();

    if (c is null)
    {
        throw new ConfigMissingException(nameof(TConfig));
    }

    // Populate config here
})
.Validate((c) =>
{
    bool valid = c.Validate();

    if (!valid)
    {
        throw new ConfigInvalidException(
            nameof(TConfig),
            c
                .GetValidationErrors()
                .ToList());
    }

    return valid;
})
.ValidateOnStart();


Whatever your TConfig is, you can always add it through AddOptions<TConfig> and later use it via IOptions<TConfig>.Value.
With AddOptions, you can use Configure and Validate methods, which you can define as you described above and are also dependency injection enabled (meaning you can use there registered services).
Here's sample code:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJsonFileProvider, JsonFileProvider>();

builder.Services
    .AddOptions<JsonOptionsFromFile>()
    .Configure<IJsonFileProvider>((jsonOptions, jsonFileProvider) =>
    {

    })
    .Validate<IJsonFileProvider>((jsonOptions, jsonFileProvider) =>
    {
        return true;
    })
    .ValidateOnStart();


Didn't knew that was possible! The only issue I am facing is the Action delegate, how can I copy the entire jsonOptions fetched from the jsonFileProvider to the passed in jsonOptions?

@Mivaweb In Configure method - you define one param of type JsonFileProvider and use it to populate first param of type jsonOptions

Correct, see my update in the question. I need a way to populate the generic TConfig. If it was a func I could just return c.

Solved it by passing the config param to the config loader service and use the populateobject method from Newtonsoft to populate the config.
